# PHP Composer Autoloading takes forever

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

Whenever I run `composer update` the 'Generating autoload files' part always takes forever (sometimes up to 2 full minutes). I've ran it with the `--profile` flag to pinpoint this issue.

I've read multiple articles on it, but I still can't understand why it takes this long on my projects, and if it's even useful for my projects?
I'm running into this whenever I'm deploying changes live, and I want that deployment to be as fast as possible. 
I've tried to run it with `--no-dev` flag, but that doesn't change anything.

So my question is, why would autoloading take so long (and how could I improve its speed)?

Comment: How many packages are you using?

Comment: Four in total, one that changes regularly, two that never change, and one that changes a couple times per year.

Comment: How many files/directories contains your project? It does not matter if it is PHP file or image.

Comment: Uhm, very very much, in the thousands?

Comment: Composer scans all files in your project, it could take some time if the number of files is large.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on how your autoloader is configured in your `composer.json` file, composer can scan every single file in your project looking for classes. For big projects, this can take quite some time. Especially when using the `classmap` setting in composer. To speed up the autoload generation, you would want to use something like the PSR-4 autoloader, specifying a namespace prefix for your classes, but this might require some changes in your project depending on how your project and classes are structured.

Comment: This is useful information! I have a requirement in my composer file that checks if the CMS has updates. I think that's where the biggest loading time comes from then. Is there a way to exclude this from the autoloader? The CMS updates but a few times per year

Comment: Ok I found [this] (https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#exclude-files-from-classmaps). if I add the /cms/ folder from /vendor/ in there, would that work? I tried it and it still takes a long time. Is there maybe a way to "profile" what the autoloader does? Or better still, do I really need the autoloader?